# QoS/traffic-limit on internal ports in OpenVSwitch

Tags: qos, rate-limiting, openvswitch, openstack-neutron

I am currently trying to put traffic control on our OpenStack cloud and my questions in one sentence would be: **is it possible at all to rate-limit particular port with type internal?**

The whole story is as following:
We are running OpenStack Neutron network over OpenVSwitch. Datapath can be found here:

[image]

Hence, to limit upload/download bandwidth of a particular sub-network, the most intuitive approach is to put QoS rules on L3 router agents, namely port qr-XXXXXX-XX and qg-XXXXX-XX in Neutron nodes. Both of them are **internal type** in OVS-system and I have tried following commands:

1.

```
ovs-vsctl set interface qr-XXXXXX-XX ingress_policing_rate=2000000

ovs-vsctl set interface qr-XXXXXX-XX ingress_policing_rate=2000
```

2.

```
ovs-vsctl -- set Port qr-XXXXXX-XX qos=@newqos \

-- --id=@newqos create QoS type=linux-htb other-config:max-rate=2000000 queues=0=@q0 \

-- --id=@q0 create Queue other-config:min-rate=2000000
```

Although neither of them seem to be effective when I try iperf within in VMs.

Meanwhile, I do achieve rate limit when apply exactly same commands on qvoXXXXXX-XX, which is connected to each VM. I've noticed that they are normal types.

Therefore, I suspect that rate limit does not support internal port, which connects two network namespaces in linux.

Thanks for your valuable time and I truly appreciate your help!

Comment: see this link http://openvswitch.org/pipermail/discuss/2015-March/017098.html for help. hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day's googling.I found it seems rate-limiting is not working on internal port.ref is http://openvswitch.org/pipermail/discuss/2013-April/009586.html

Comment: Hey, thanks! I am glad my experiment result could be confirmed by others. Do you think it is rather a "feature" than lack in functionalities?

Comment: emm, it is a problem indeed.After a long time study, I just use tc to do qos myself.